# IntelliJ Spring declaring base-package and class in .xml file

Tags: java, xml, spring, intellij-idea, package

I am completely new to using Spring in IntelliJ. I have an .xml file and in the file I am trying to declare the package so it knows where to access the files, but IntelliJ shows the package name in red and the error seems to be a "cannot resolve package" and the Inspection info says "Spring XML model validation." Is there a way to solve this?

[Screenshot of project in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBXG7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is a "non-project", basically.
As of now, you don't have any directory marked as *sources*. Thus, you have no packages at all.

That's why IDEA is showing all that red.

It seems you "imported" the project from VSCode (I see a `.vs` directory), but unsuccessfully.
What I recommend you to do is recreating the project from scratch using Maven or Gradle, and only after, importing the source files under the `src` directory.

---

This

[image]

means IDEA is recognizing the file only as a `.java` file, but without being part of a project.